# Is it possible to update my graphic card drivers?

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, opengl

This is what the lspci -v command shows in the VGA compatible controller section:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx Integrated Graphics Controller (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Dell Device 048e
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
Memory at f0200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
I/O ports at 18d0 [size=8]
Memory at d0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at f0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915
```

i915 is only compatible with OpenGL 1.4 and cannot use shaders and I'd like to use some Open GL 2.0 functionalities.

Is it possible to update the drivers or is my hardware limited to OpenGL 1.4 ?

Comment: Have you tried running jockey-gtk? This searches for updated or "additional" drivers. (Just trying to check the simple things first.)

Comment: I just tried, jockey-gtk doesn't find anything.

Comment: You could also open synaptic and search i915. There is an xserver-xorg-intel package that may work for you. I have no way of testing it on my hardware.

Comment: To answer the secondary question, "Is it possible to update (to use Open GL 2.0)? This article indicates yes. http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=OTk4Mg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intel has not additional drivers (restricted drivers) available for Linux. The drivers are all open source.

If you want to update the driver for Intel graphics card you can add a PPA where the newest drivers included and update from there.

Example . [Ubuntu X - Team](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates)

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If you want to revert back (undo)

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: I did what you told me, it updated the drivers, but the glxinfo | grep version command still indicates "OpenGL version string: 1.4 Mesa 8.0.2". Any idea on how to tell it to use OpenGL 2 ?

Comment: If your graphics card (hardware) not supporting OpenGL 2.0 , then the driver cannot do much (I think). Take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_GMA) and according to your graphics card model , see if supports OpenGL 2.0

Comment: The card DOES support 2.0: http://phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=OTk4Mg

Comment: The link is dead.